# Executing CMD Command from a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I have seen many similar questions but none of them is related to the execution of a CMD command such as `ipconfig` from a PS script (.ps1).

If you type those commands on the PS console they work fine but once on a script they don't, below you can see an example:

```
PS C:\Users\TestQro> adb devices
List of devices attached

PS C:\Users\TestQro> adb devices | Select-String -Quiet List
True
```

returns True because the `Select-String` finds the word "List" in the response of the command "adb devices" which is the expected behavior. But if I go and put the same command into a .ps1 script file PS answers when running:

```
PS C:\TesterInfo> ./TunnerApp.ps1

cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters: InputObject[0]:
```

How should I type the normal CMD commands inside of a script?
Why is it waiting for parameters on script but right in the console it works fine?

Comment: For help with code that isn't working: **show** the code that isn't working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. The code is only this line: "adb devices | select-string -Quiet List"

Comment: Then please try starting a clean PowerShell instance from a CMD window (`powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile`) and run the script from there. Do you still get the same prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your output there

```
PS C:\TesterInfo> ./TunnerApp.ps1

cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters: InputObject[0]:
```

It looks like you have a `Write-Output` statement somewhere in your PowerShell script that does not have any input. Look for an empty `Write-Output` statement somewhere

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping out but the only line in the script is the same you see in the console so I don't know why the parameter is needed in the script and not when typed:                                                                                                                 
adb devices | select-string -Quiet List

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoDiaz I see, maybe try piping out the adb devices to a file and grab the output of that and search for your value.

`adb devices > C:\temp\adb.txt
$devices = Get-Content C:\temp\adb.txt`

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to as *CMD commands* are actually executables in the `Windows` or `System32` folders (or some other `PATH` environment variable path).  As such, you can call them like you would any executable using the *call operator*:

```
& "$Env:SystemRoot\System32\IPCONFIG.exe"
```

---

### [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#special-operators)

Comment: External commands can be invoked as bare words without using the call operator as long as there is no space in the filename or path. `ipconfig`, `& ipconfig`, and `& "ipconfig"` should all do the same.